# HTML5 video - Stream a rendering video

Tags: html, video-streaming

If I am rendering a video to "test.mp4", how can the user stream what has been rendered so far?

For example, the user can watch/receive the frames of the video that have been created/rendered so far without waiting till the full rendering of the video to start watching the video.

Thanks!

Comment: A live-stream is not just a file, it must be multiple fragments (chunks) that the user can request.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible with a regular MP4. You must use webm or a fragmented MP4.